# How to change php value after clicking a button using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I want to change `howPost()` function name to `articlePost()` using jQuery after clicking a button. I simply want another function to run after clicking it. How do I accomplish that?

```
<?php
  for($i = 0; $i <howPost(); $i++){
    echo drawPost($i+1);
  }
?>
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between client side and server side programming first. You can certainly do this by making an ajax request and executing a particular function but you cannot swap the method directly using jQuery

Comment: The PHP for loop occurs before or after the click?

Comment: after the click

Answer (score 0):

You can't "change" your PHP file using jQuery, PHP is executed server-side. So once you have your response, all you can do is another HTTP request to the server, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840431/6160379) SO accepted answer.

It should clarify things for you. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need `Ajax` to accomplish that.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You create an html form with html and then add `EventListeners` with e.g. jQuery which triggers the form using ajax. Ajax makes an actual HTTP-Request which processes the data sent along with the ajax call.